# Content / software tool distribution system

Tags: document-management, version-control, desktop-client, information-management, ecm

To begin with, the software which is searched for can be of any scope, ranging from a commercial tool over an open source project, which have to be adapted, to a framework/library as support for an in-house implementation.

The topic is basically some sort of *distribution system*:

**Administration part**

Admins store *content*, which should be distributed to users, into a system. Content is represented as regular files like scripts, XML, PDF, other text files (UTF-8 preferred) and so forth. Related content items are grouped. It should be possible to have different *revisions / versions* of each content to provide updates or fixes. There is a *user management* and *access control* defined on the content based on an arbitrary number of *user attributes*.

**Client part**

On the other side there is a tool used by the users to see only those content they were authorized. Users have typically only *reading access*. Further it should be possible to *track* the content usage of the user to collect a statistic.

While the client part is more or less quite simple I like to hear ideas for the administration part.

**Technical requirements**

- Windows

Comment: Is browser-based okay?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer There is a preference for a desktop client, but I am thankful for any inputs.

Comment: Have you looked at existing DMS? I've worked with Alfresco a long time ago and I think it would do such things as you need (but its Browser based). If regular DMS don't roll, please explain why.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Didn't. That's a good pointer, thanks.
Would have one or two further questions on that.. you make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is an [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) system with a desktop client.
Angelo's suggestion of Alfresco is great, but let me suggest a lighter solution that also matches your requirements:

## Server side

[NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com/) stores a hierarchy of folders and documents of any type/size.

- Related content can be grouped in folders, or by using custom types (metadata, independent from the files' actual type or extension).
- Modifications are saved as new versions.
- Add several groups to each user: The user will have access to this file or that folder if they belong to the correct group.
- A server-side audit log allows you to check who have downloaded/uploaded/modified what.
- Free, and open source.

## Client side

[CmisSync](http://cmissync.com/) synchronize your documents to/from your computer's filesystem, handling conflicts like Dropbox.

If needed, NemakiWare also has a web interface that shows your documents, and allows you to preview them, download them, or move/delete/copy/etc.

*Disclaimer: My company makes both NemakiWare and CmisSync*